# Convert Clipped Item Into Normal Path In Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I created a semi-circle with the clipping feature, but it shows up as a group of two items. Like this:

[image: Not A Path]

But i just want a **normal path**, could i do this anyway?

Comment: As in @Realrawr answer, you can draw an half-circle. Else you can use the [difference](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) operation instead of clip the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres my answer to this question from the Google+ Query on the Inscape Community:

to create that shape I'd just use the arc tool - even if you draw a circle, you can select the circle tool (F5) and select the circle and change your start and end degrees.  But is the posted image just a simple example to make the point?

I guess if I was going to cut down the circle to make a half-circle (same can be done with more complex shapes) I'd select the circle and the rectangle above and chose Path -> Intersection. That cuts it to the shape I'm wanting to have left over - and leaves all the remaining points as an editable path.